# Reactjs Snackbar that show progress on its self

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, progress, snackbar, notistack

I learn React JavaScript and wanted to have snackbar that could show progress once it is showen. Like the Snackbar is showed as usual sliding out from the lover left and immediately start to show % progress for let's say some download.

I tried the [notistack](https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack) but it need to show the snackbar again with the new progress but I want to show progress on one snackbar

This below is [notistack](https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack) example. Every time I click button the `onClick()` show the Snackbar again with the incremented `xc`,  when I want the `xc` increment to be showen on the same snackbar not pop out again

```
let xc = 0;

function onClick() {
    xc += 1;
    enqueueSnackbar({
        message: xc,
        preventDuplicate: false,
        options: {
            key: 'item.name',
            variant: 'success',
            //  action: key => <Button onClick={() => closeSnackbar(key)}>dismiss me</Button>,
        },
    });
}
```

I have looked into a number of Snackbars like
[material-ui](https://material-ui.com/components/snackbars/)
[notistack](https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack)
[material-ui-snackbar-provider](https://github.com/TeamWertarbyte/material-ui-snackbar-provider#readme)

Can anyone give some hint if this is possible or if there some library that can do this. Preferable some Redux supported lib

Answer (score 0):

You can write your custom variant as pointed out by [the documentation](https://notistack.com/features/customization#custom-component).
Adding [a progress bar](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-progress/#linear-with-label) at the bottom of your Snackbar may fit your need :D

Answer (score 0):

`react-toastify` supports this incredibly easily out of the box, and has a whole page dedicated to this use case in the documentation: https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/update-toast.

### notistack

As far as I can tell, you can't really do this with `notistack`.  While you can pass in a `key` and use `preventDuplicate: true` to ensure that it only shows one of each message with key, if you try to call `enqueueSnackbar` on a key that already exists, you won't see an update, unless you manually call `closeSnackbar(key)` on that key to dismiss it first, and wait for the UI to update before calling `enqueueSnackbar()` again.  I have a [CodeSandbox demonstrating this](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/notistack-update-demo-pjf8vv?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqj9tky200063b6ip8ots762%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqj9tky200023b6indr6lvdf%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqj9tky200033b6iowzv3yoa%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqj9tky200053b6iad61zxio%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B62.79895090566347%252C37.20104909433653%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clqj9tky200023b6indr6lvdf%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqj9tky200013b6ifru31vwo%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fpublic%252Findex.html%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqj9tky200023b6indr6lvdf%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqj9tky200013b6ifru31vwo%2522%257D%252C%2522clqj9tky200053b6iad61zxio%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqj9tky200043b6i6nacti4i%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqj9tky200053b6iad61zxio%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqj9tky200043b6i6nacti4i%2522%257D%252C%2522clqj9tky200033b6iowzv3yoa%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqj9tky200033b6iowzv3yoa%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A20.5%257D).

That's almost certainly not what you're looking for.

Note: if you don't want to pre-determine a `key`, you can just use the return value of `enqueueSnackbar()`, which will be a randomly generated key if you don't specify one in the options parameter.